# Tagging or labeling with Jenkins and Visual Studio Online

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

We are in the early stages of using Visual Studio Online (VSO) for version control and Jenkins to build, test, and deploy. (No option to change from VSO at this point.) Things are working to build, test, and deploy but there is currently no tagging/labeling happening. Is using tf.exe the only way to accomplish tagging with Jenkins and VSO? I've seen some Jenkins plugins that tag and facilitate the release process with Git and other SCMs but not VSO or TFS so far. Does anyone know of any ways of doing this rather than tf.exe from the command line? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Commandline is one option, and probably the simplest one. You could use the TFS Client Object Model or the TFS Java SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616) to build a custom action for Jenkins.

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git for source control in VSO?